# Executing SQL directly; no cursor in PHP when calling a stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm getting the following error when trying to execute a stored procedure from PHP using sqlsrv driver:

```
Executing SQL directly; no cursor
```

Comment: As a first step, I always suggest Googling an error. Often you are not the first to experience a problem. Try Googling "PHP sqlsrv Executing SQL directly; no cursor"

Comment: @PhpMyCoder and google bring me here

Answer (score 4):

Add a cursor option to your connection:

```
$connection = odbc_connect('host','username','password', 1)
          or die('Connection failed!');
```

After password insert cursor_option **1** <-- this option was missing.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when I used code that basically did this:

```
$options = array( "Scrollable"=>SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC);
$sql = "exec dbs_webgetnextcount 'expense'";
sqlsrv_query($db,$sql,null,$options);
```

I fixed it by not setting the cursor.

```
$sql = "exec dbs_webgetnextcount 'expense'";
sqlsrv_query($db,$sql);
```

PS. I was doing the `CURSOR_STATIC` option on my select statements so that `sqlsrv_num_rows()` would give a correct number.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as Jon but I figured since it is just a warning generated by the sql data access component and the query still completes successfully you can disable it in sqlsrv.exe using `sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Could be a permissions issue:

- http://griffo.info/tellme/2009/05/executing-sql-directly-no-cursor/