# sqlsrv_num_rows not working for Stored procedures

Tags: php, sql-server

I m using PHP-SQRSRV driver to read my MSSQL database.

When I use sqlsrv_num_rows, i get 0 results as cursor can not be set properly. This happens just in case of Stored Procedures.
I have used SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC & SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET both. None worked.

Initially I got this error : Executing SQL directly, no cursor.. [Executing SQL directly; no cursor in PHP when calling a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777709/executing-sql-directly-no-cursor-in-php-when-calling-a-stored-procedure)

But then after setting [sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0);] that was resolved.
Now all I m getting is 0 or -1 as output.

I want just counts of the records, not the whole record. And I have to use a stored procedure.

Please help me find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures do not return an implcit row count.

You will need to amend your stored procedure to generate row count(s) and return them either as [`OUTPUT` parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc644932.aspx) from the procedure or as an additional result-set.

How you do this will depend on the nature of your procedure and what you're trying to count. If you are counting rows which are being affected by one or more `SELECT`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements within the procedure, you can use the [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) internal parameter to set the value of an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
<some SQL operation>    
SET @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
```

If you're simply counting rows in tables, you can assign the output of a simple count query to a parameter:

```
SELECT @rowcount = COUNT(1) FROM <some table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed Harper.. I have gone through this solution.
The problem is I can not modify all Stored Procs. They are managed by another party. Also, they are being used in other part of the system. 
Now the only way left for me is to get all the data in a PHP array and then count the length of it.
Anyways, thanks a lot for helping.